# Unterschied "zu sich kommen" und "sich wieder fangen"

Tags: word-usage

könnte mir jemand den Unterschied zwischen den beiden Phrasen erklären?

LG Nika

Comment: What did you find in a dictionary? https://dict.leo.org/german-english/zu+sich+kommen and https://dict.leo.org/german-english/sich+wieder+fangen --- what exactly is still unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Zu sich kommen** bezeichnet üblicherweise das Erwachen nach einem ungeplanten¹ Verlust des Bewusstseins. Beispielfälle sind das Einnicken und die Ohnmacht.

> Er nickte beim Fernsehen ein, kam nach zehn Minuten aber wieder zu
>   sich.
>
> Glück gehabt! Er kam wieder zu sich, der auf den Brettern liegende,
>   ausgeknockte Boxer.

**Wieder fangen** kann man sich z. B. nach

> - einem Trauerfall mit Depression
> - einem Schock angesichts einer überraschenden Kündigung
> - einer Krebsdiagnose

Es beschreibt im Allgemeinen das Überwundenhaben einer seelischen Ausnahmesituation.

> Er erschoss seine Frau, und dann verlor er die Nerven. Es dauerte
>   Wochen, bis er sich wieder gefangen hatte.²

<sub>¹Ausnahme: Ein aus medizinischen Gründen absichtlich betäubter Patient, der schließlich wieder zu sich kommt.</sub>
<sub>²Manch einer verliert natürlich erst die Nerven und erschießt dann seine Frau.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

**Zu sich kommen** bezieht sich auf eine überwundende Ohnmacht.

> Der Radfahrer kam nach dem Sturz nicht wieder zu sich.

**Sich wieder fangen** bezieht sich auf einen Nervenzusammenbruch.

> Seine Begleiterin fing sich erst wieder, als er die Augen öffnete.

Answer (score 2):

Jankas Antwort ist schon sehr gut. **Sich wieder fangen** kann man sich aber auch nach einem Lachanfall.

Answer (score 1):

"Zu sich kommen" has at least 2 meanings:
1) To wake up from swoon or anesthesia
2) To lose a strange opinion or state of mind

"sich wieder fangen" stands for:
1) Becoming healthy again (after illness)
2) To leave a wrong way of life which is destructive or harmful to one's self or others.

Comment: Why did you answer in English?